# c# implicitly download file from ftp server without a 3rd party library

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm trying to connect to an ftp server implicitly in order to download a file. I'm having trouble establishing a connection. Here is what I am trying.

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("ftp://server/", 990))
  using (SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), true))
  {
    // Start SSL/TLS Handshake
    sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("localhost");

    // Setup a delegate for writing FTP commands to the SSL stream
    Action<string> WriteCommand = delegate(string command)
    {
      byte[] commandBytes =
          Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command + Environment.NewLine);
      sslStream.Write(commandBytes, 0, commandBytes.Length);
    };

    // Write raw FTP commands to the SSL stream
    WriteCommand("USER user");
    WriteCommand("PASS password");

    // Connect to data port to download the file 
  }
```

**What I need:**

> 1) Code to establish an ftp server connection implicitly
>
> 2) Code to Download file over this connection

Comment: I've tried numerous approaches and still nothing. Every time I try to get a response, my main error is "unable to connect to remote server". I am able to connect to remote server via filezilla, however while connecting via filezilla I'm prompted with prompt "Trust this certificate and carry on connecting?" Do I need to clear or ignore bad certificates? But that would be after the initial connection is established correct?

Answer (score 1):

```
   using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("ftp://server/", 990))
```

Port 990 is the assigned port number for the control port for the [FTPS protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS).  Which is, as you describe, a way to transfer files using encryption with TLS or SSL.  Hopefully the former, not much point in using SSL anymore since the [POODLE attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE) was revealed.  Writing your own client for it is unusual, this has of course been done before.

Your question is very light on details why you think you need to write your own client.  The correct answer therefore is likely to be the simple one, you are overlooking that FTPS support is already built-in to the .NET Framework.

Use the [FtpWebRequest.EnableSsl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.enablessl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

Comment: "why you think you need to write your own client" Reply: Is there another option?

Comment: Click the link at the bottom of the post for the other option.  If that doesn't work then you haven't nearly spent enough time on your question to explain what is special about this server.

Answer (score 1):

Change below line and I believe you should be able to connect.

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("ftp://server/", 990))
```

Change above line to:

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("server", 990))
```

Also try using default FTP port 21:

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("server", 21))
```

Answer (score 0):

SslStream will not work with ftp, only ssl.

You can use the FtpWebRequest class to retrieve data over ftp:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The article in the link above has several examples, one of which is to download an ftp file from an ftp server:

```
public static bool DisplayFileFromServer(Uri serverUri)
{
    // The serverUri parameter should start with the ftp:// scheme. 
    if (serverUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
    WebClient request = new WebClient();

    // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");
    try 
    {
        byte [] newFileData = request.DownloadData (serverUri.ToString());
        string fileString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newFileData);
        Console.WriteLine(fileString);
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and it returned false. Should the uri be fttp://website.com/file.xml?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestGetExample
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

            Console.WriteLine("Download Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            reader.Close();
            response.Close();  
        }
    }
}
```

Taken from **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229711%28v=vs.100%29.aspx**

Answer (score 0):

You've said you don't want to *purchase* a third-party library to achieve this, but there is [an FTP client implementation at CodePlex](https://netftp.codeplex.com/) that claims to support FTPS.

It's MIT licenced, so if you're not willing to pull in a third-party dependency, you could review the source code to see if there's any implementation there you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code:

```
public void DownloadFromFTP( string ftpLocation, string fileName, string localFolder, string login, string password )
{
    var remoteFilePath = ftpLocation + @"/" + fileName;

    FtpWebResponse response = null;

    try
    {
        var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create( new Uri( remoteFilePath ) );
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential( login, password );

        response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        var localPath = string.Format( @"{0}\{1}", localFolder, fileName );

        using( var fs = File.Create( localPath ) )
        {
            stream.CopyTo( fs );
        }
    }
    catch( Exception ex )
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        if( response != null )
        {
            response.Close();
        }
    }
}
```